# MS SQL Server slow UPDATE query with Eager Spool despite index within SSMS on local server

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing, query-optimization

I'm running a SQL query within SSMS on the computer that is running Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition. The query seems to be significantly slower than it should.

I added an index on the columns in question that the query uses, and the duration of the query improved from around 120 seconds to around 85 seconds, but I still think it should be faster, comparing it to other queries between the same tables, with similar column data types, that complete in less than a second.

The query updates a summary table by aggregating data from a worktable.

The summary table is approx 10,000 rows and 30 columns of mixed VARCHAR, FLOAT and INT columns.

The worktable table is approx 7,500,000 rows, with a similar number of columns and a similar mix of column data types.

Looking at the execution plan, it seems to do an Index Spool (Eager Spool) which, from reading, often can mean that the query is missing an index.

I have a non-clustered index on the three columns the query...queries.

The complete query is:

```
UPDATE SummaryTable 
SET LifeTeacherTopScore = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                           FROM WorkTable AS T1 
                           WHERE T1.Z_date < SummaryTable.Z_date 
                             AND T1.Teacher = SummaryTable.Teacher 
                             AND T1.Score = 1)
WHERE SummaryTable.Teacher <> ''
```

The execution plan is here:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByEo9Ru42

On the WorkTable table I have a non-clustered index on Z_date, Teacher and Score.

There are around 10,000 unique entries in the Z_date column, around 25,000 unique entries in the Teacher column, and around 30 unique entries in the Score column.
The teacher column contains around 1,500,000 NULL entries, hence why I exclude NULLs within the above query by finishing it with:

```
where SummaryTable.Teacher <> ''
```

Z_date format is DATE, Teacher format is VARCHAR(50), Score format is INT.

After doing an Index Scan (NonClustered), using the index I added, the query then does an Index Spool (Eager Spool), with a cost of 87%, which seems to be the reason for the duration of the scan.

I have read dozens of pages re slow queries, indexes, etc, without finding any page that has helped to isolate the issue.

Any suggestions, recommendations, on improving the performance of this query greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will likely be much better off using a window function to calculate the cumulative totals by date

Comment: You could try pre-aggregating (in a CTE or derived table). Sub-queries like that can be run once per row, rather than processed as a set, which would be detrimental to the performance. Do you have an indexes on `WorkTable`? What are the definitions of those indexes? The query plan shows that a scan is being performed, which could be the sign of a non-covering index.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith, I will look into using window functions... I'm not familiar with them at all unfortunately.
Generally, for the query in question, I'm trying to get a aggregate of WorkTable.Score that is before the Z_date in SummaryTable.

Comment: Thanks @ThomA.  I'm also not familiar with CTEs or derived tables, so I will have to look into them as well.
Yes, I do have a non-clustered index on Z_date, Teacher and Score. 
That is the only index on WorkTable.
How do I show the definitions of those indexes?
If, within SSMS, I expand the WorkTable table, and then expand Indexes, it shows only the one index.
Double clicking that, it reports that its nonclustered, and under Index key columns, it lists Z_date, Score, Teacher, with sort order as Ascending, and data types as date, int, and varchar(50). If that helps?

Comment: Post the DDL of your index(es) in the question, @joshAU .

Comment: @MartinSmith. I tried doing a window function, but could not seem to get it to work, as it essentially did a total cumulative count irrespective of the teacher...probably more my lack of knowledge I guess.
For each Teacher row in the SummaryTable, I need to get a count of the rows in worktable that match that Teacher, and that are older than the Z_date on the same row and that have a Score of 1.
I'll keep looking though as a couple of window function queries I tried had surprisingly fast speeds. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomA Do you mean the actual query used to create the index?
IF so, it was:
`CREATE INDEX IX_NCI_Z_date_Teacher_Score ON WORKTABLE (Z_date, Teacher, Score);`

Comment: OMG! Thanks @O.Jones!
I did not realise the order of columns would matter so much..
I deleted the original index, then recreated it but swapping Z_date and Score around.
The query now completes in 20 seconds - thank you so much.
The eager spool has gone.
Thanks also re Show Actual Execution Plan - I'd checked that, but for the above query it didn't recommend any new index. 
If you could put your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer.
Thank you, and thanks to everyone else as well for your input and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of columns in an index matters. Try `(Score, Teacher, Z_Date)`. What's this about?

SQL Server and other RDBMS systems use so-called B-Tree indexes. Think of them as old-school telephone books. To find the rows after a certain Z_Date for a particular Score and Teacher, you visit the section of the book with Scores of 1. You then look for the teacher, then you look for the first eligible date. You can then look at each row in turn.

In indexing terms, you random-access the B-Tree index to the first eligible row, then scan the rows sequentially.  This only works if, in the index, the Z_Date column comes *after* the other two columns.  If Z_Date were first in the column you'd have to pick through all the rows looking for matching ones, and that is expensive.

**Pro tip**: In SSMS: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it, thank  you.
Another virtually identical query, on the same columns, still takes approx 70 seconds.
The only difference is the second last line where it checks if it is less than 5, rather than 1. 
Any suggestions?

The query is:


`UPDATE SummaryTable 
SET LifeTeacherHighScores = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM WorkTable AS T1 
WHERE T1.Z_date < SummaryTable.Z_date 
AND T1.Teacher = SummaryTable.Teacher 
 AND T1.Score <5)
WHERE SummaryTable.Teacher <> ''`

Comment: A super-efficient BTREE index range scan is possible only with a single inequality filter condition. Yours has two.

Comment: Ah, OK, that make sense.
So, I changed the code so that the first line became SET `LifeTeacherHighScores = LifeTeacherHighScores+....`, then reran the code above 4 times, incrementing the `AND T1.Score <n` value by one each time, which gives me the total number of scores from 1 to 4, for each teacher, correctly.
As each one takes only around a second, the total time is only around 5 seconds, instead of 70 seconds. 
I'm happy!
Thanks again for your help and advice. 
Greatly appreciated.

Comment: `T1.Score IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` might also be efficient. Give it a try.

Comment: Yes, that is much neater code, and takes slightly less time than duplicating and adding 4 times. (4.85 seconds vs 5.27 seconds)
Because I already had LifeTeacherTopScore in the other column, I just had to add that and then only run the code three times to get the top 4, which meant that it was marginally faster again. (3.79 seconds) so I'll go with that. 
Thanks again!

Comment: I had three other slower queries that all took around 70-90 seconds to run, so, I decided to add another clause to them that covered every possible outcome, i.e. `AND T1.Score IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10)`.
All 3 queries now run in a few seconds.
Somewhat counter-intuitive.
I don't understand why this works, as Score has a max of 10, so the AND clause covers every possibility, and is therefore redundant, but I'm happy to accept it. :)

Comment: As for the *why*, take a look at the query plans. It's likely that `IN(1,2,3)` does the union of three fast index scans where `<= 3` does a single full table or full index scan.

Comment: The `IN (1,2,3)` does just an Index Seek, whereas the `<4` does a Index Scan, then an Eager Spool, then a Filter.
I don't understand why this query: `UPDATE SummaryTable SET LifeTeacherTotalScore = (select count(*) from WorkTable as T1 WHERE T1.Z_date < SummaryTable.Z_date AND T1.Teacher = SummaryTable.Teacher ) WHERE SummaryTable .Teacher <> ''` takes 80 secs, but if I just add the clause `AND T1.Score IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`, it only takes 15 secs... even though there are only 10 possible options for Score, so it includes everything. 
Why does that make it skip the eager Spool?